# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Tags: json-deserialization, attributeerror

It's a two part question,

```
import face_recognition
import os
import json
loadarr=[]
encodearr=[]
for i in range(0, 4):
    loadarr.append(face_recognition.load_image_file( "brad"+str(i+1)+".jpg"))
    encodearr.append(face_recognition.face_encodings(loadarr[i])[0])
encodearr = encodearr.tolist()
# print(encodearr)
encodedDic = {"des": encodearr}

with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(encodedDic,outfile)
```

When I tried to convert the list `encodearr` as value of the key `"des"` (without .tolist()) it shows
`TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable` .Then I added .tolist() to encode arr as show. it shows `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'`, brad1 to brad5 are the jpg files in the directory.

Comment: encodearr is already a list. So, you can delete the line encodearr = encodearr.tolist() and it works.

Comment: as i said without adding the to list it shows `TypeError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround using numpy.

```
import face_recognition
import os
import json
import numpy as np
encodearr=[]
for i in range(0, 4):
    load=face_recognition.load_image_file( "brad"+str(i+1)+".jpg")
    encodearr.append(face_recognition.face_encodings(loadarr)[0])
reshapped_array = np.reshape(encodearr,(total_images,128)   //each image is an array consisting 128 images
encodedDic = {"des": reshapped_array }
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(encodedDic,outfile)
```